# Loading text from a file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am making an Iphone drinking card game app.
All the card mean something different and i want the user to be able to press an info button and then show a new screen with information about the current card. How can i make a document to load text from instead of using a bunch og long strings?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into plist files - they can be loaded quite easily into the various collection objects and edited with the plist editor in Xcode.

For instance, if you organize your data as a dictionary, the convenience constructor

```
+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL
```

from NSDictionary would provide you with as many easily accessible strings as you need.

This method is useful if you consider your strings primarily data as opposed to UI elements.

**Update:**

As @Alex Nichol suggested, here is how you can do it in practice:

To create a plist file:

- In your Xcode project, for instance in the Supporting Files group, select New File > Resource > Property List
- You can save the file in `en.lproj`, to aid in localization
- In the Property list editing pane, select Add Row (or just hit return)
- Enter a key name (for instance `user1`) and a value (for instance "Joe")

To read the contents:

```
NSURL *plistURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Property List" withExtension:@"plist"];

NSLog(@"URL: %@", plistURL);

NSDictionary *strings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:plistURL];

NSString *user1 = [strings objectForKey:@"user1"];

NSLog(@"User 1: %@", user1);
```

Comment: I would also mention how one would create a Plist resource in Xcode, and how you could load such a resource file as an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A plist, a JSON string, and an SQLite database walked into a bar ...

Oops!!  I mean those are the three most obvious alternatives.  The JSON string is probably the easiest to create and "transport", though it's most practical to load the entire thing into an NSDictionary and/or NSArray, vs read from the file as each string is accessed.

The SQLite DB is the most general, and most speed/storage efficient for a very large number (thousands) of strings, but it takes some effort to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

In my other answer, I suggest the use of a dictionary if your texts are mostly to be considered as data. However, if your strings are UI elements (alert texts, window titles, etc.) you might want to look into `strings` files and `NSBundle`'s support for them.

Strings files are ideally suited for localization, the format is explained [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6).

To read them into you app, use something like this:

```
NSString *text1 = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"TEXT1", @"myStringsFile", @"Comment");
```

If you call your file `Localizable.strings`, you can even use a simpler form:

```
NSString *str1 = NSLocalizedString(@"String1", @"Comment on String1");
```

A useful discussion [here](http://www.stone.com/The_Cocoa_Files/Internationalize_Your_App.html) - a bit old, but still useful.